# Regular expression for validating non-negative integer

Tags: regex

I am trying to do input validation for a non-negative integer (whole numbers from 0 through infinity). My current regex pattern `/^[1-9]+\d*$/` is not sufficient because it invalidates '0'.

How can I modify it to accept '0'?

Comment: try `/^[0-9]+\d*$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just change 1-9 to 0-9, it will also accept numbers like 0234, 0002, 012, etc. 
If you don't want to accept these, I suggest that you try this:

```
^([1-9]\d*|0)$
```

Also, you might want to remove the '+' after [1-9]. It's unnecessary because there's already \d*.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much! You're right in that I do not want any zero pre-padding either (aside from the single allowed instance). I'll make sure to remove the redundant '+'.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 0 in the bracket    '

```
[01-9]+\d*$
```

or

```
[0-9]+\d*$
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! Unfortunately this regex pattern will also validate additional values like 0002 which is undesirable for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

If a negative lookahead `(?!` is supported, you could also match all digits if it does not start with a zero followed by another digit.

```
^(?!0\d)\d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g2TkrY/1)